# Using a stored procedure on each row in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some accounts and vendors. I need to run a stored procedure on each row to add them to other tables.

Everything im reading says to try not use loops, which makes sense. But can anyone tell me how I would do this without them?

Sample table

```
 AccountNum | VendorName
------------------------
1234       | Vendor1
2345       | Vendor2
3456       | Vendor1
4567       | Vendor3
```

Then my Stored Procedure is below. So i need to pass in the account numbe rand vendor from each row into the stored procedure below. (Dont worry about the premise number and user, they can be N/A for all). So is there a way to do this without looping through each row? Im using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Cheers

```
USE [PEEL_ICEM]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AddAccountNumber]    Script Date:     2/11/2016 3:59:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddAccountNumber]
@AccountNumber nvarchar(150),
@UserName nvarchar(100),    
@PremiseNumber nvarchar(150) = Null,
@VendorName nvarchar (100)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET XACT_ABORT on

IF @VendorName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CustomerID int
    DECLARE @LIPharseID int
    DECLARE @ExportLabelID int
    DECLARE @CustVenID  int
    DECLARE @AccountNo varchar(20)
    --Get the Customer ID with the user name
    SELECT @CustomerID = [Customers].[CustomerID]
    FROM [CustomerUsers]
    INNER JOIN [Customers] ON [Customers].[CustomerID] = [CustomerUsers].CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserID = [CustomerUsers].UserID WHERE Users.Username = @UserName
    print  @CustomerID 
    --Get the VendorID from the Vendor name, test
    DECLARE @VendorID int
    SELECT @VendorID = [VendorID]  FROM [Vendors] WHERE VendorName = @VendorName
    print  @VendorID    
    BEGIN TRAN
        --Check if the customer vendor combination already exists       
        SELECT @CustVenID = [CustomerVendorID] FROM [PEEL_ICEM].[dbo].[CustomerVendors] WHERE [CustomerID] = @CustomerID AND [VendorID] = @VendorID
        print  @CustVenID
        Select @AccountNo = [AccountNumber] From [PEEL_ICEM].[dbo].[AccountVendor] WHERE [CustomerVendorID] = @CustVenID AND [AccountNumber] = @AccountNumber
        print  @AccountNo
        IF @CustVenID IS NULL  AND @VendorID <> '' AND @CustomerID <> '' 
            BEGIN                
                INSERT INTO [CustomerVendors]
                       ([CustomerID]
                       ,[VendorID])
                 VALUES
                       (@CustomerID,@VendorID)      
                SELECT @CustVenID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()                
            END 
        print  @CustVenID
        if @AccountNo is Null
            begin
                IF @CustVenID IS NOT NULL AND @AccountNumber <> ''
                    BEGIN   
                        INSERT INTO [AccountVendor]
                        ([AccountNumber]
                        ,[CustomerVendorID]
                        ,[PremiseNumber])           
                        VALUES
                        (@AccountNumber,@CustVenID, @PremiseNumber)
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    SELECT 'ERROR' as Status
                END     
            End

    COMMIT TRAN 

    SELECT [VendorName],[AccountNumber],[PremiseNumber]     
    FROM [CustomerVendors]
    LEFT JOIN [AccountVendor] ON [CustomerVendors].[CustomerVendorID] = [AccountVendor].[CustomerVendorID]
    LEFT JOIN [Vendors] ON [Vendors].[VendorID] = [CustomerVendors].[VendorID]
    WHERE [CustomerVendors].CustomerID = @CustomerID
END
```

END

Comment: Is this something you need to run against all rows often or just a one off?

Comment: how do you identify which are the records in the source table that required to add to the target table ?

Comment: It will only be run once or twice, but id still rather do it the right way so i know it for the next time i need it. All records in the source table will be added to the target table.

Comment: I think you can do it with direct `select` and `insert`..may be with more than 1 query..or use temporary table to simplify the problem..storing values in variables make you need to do loop..

Comment: Yeah thats what im looking for alright. Anywhere you can point me to to have a look at one, or do you wanna supply an answer with some example code? Thanks